# Google Maps Circle radius alternative

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

At present I am using circles to display the path of an object of a certain width in meters on a map. This is problematic because at the rate of even 15 mph the circle method would have to be taken every few hundred milliseconds so that the circles overlap so you don't get gaps between the circles. After an hour you end up with countless circles and no memory.

```
 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

 circleOptions.radius(radi); // In meters
```

Currently I can't seem to find where the google maps android api v2 supports using a polyline with set radius in meters, but only in pixel width. With varying zoom levels and screen conditions and the projection of the map this sounds rather complicated to basically highlight a path of certain width on the map with a polyline.

Has anyone seen any alternative to using the circle radius method in the api?

Comment: using a polyline,polygon or anything else for that matter is not going to fix your problem. Having that many map objects plotted on the map at one time is going to give you problems. You need to remove some if they are not in view or rethink what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @tyczj This is why I am looking for an alternative. If a polyline with set width is used, far less location points will be needed. Countless circles need to be used for overlap. A polyline of width X  would highlight the path width and would in theory only need points every few feet as it only takes 2 points to make a line... Thanks for the input.

Comment: what you want to accomplish isnt conventional so I wouldnt expect a conventional solution. Expect to be doing a lot of math, check this link for at least a starting point https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/SeVrFw9wORE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) this becomes relatively simple:

```
public static PolygonOptions getPolygonOptions(LatLng point1, LatLng point2, float widthInMeters) {

    double heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(point1, point2);
    double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);

    LatLng corner1 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, widthInMeters / 2, heading + 90);
    LatLng corner2 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, widthInMeters / 2, heading - 90);
    LatLng corner3 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(corner2, distance, heading + 180);
    LatLng corner4 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(corner3, widthInMeters, heading + 90);

    return new PolygonOptions().add(corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4);
}
```

And then add polygons connecting your points:

```
map.addPolygon(
        getPolygonOptions(point1, point2, 50)
                .fillColor(Color.BLACK)
);
map.addPolygon(
        getPolygonOptions(point2, point3, 50)
                .fillColor(Color.BLACK)
);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what values are needed at intialization for point1, point2, and point3? I'm assuming because I'm moving from a stop at a fixed location the current location say location.getPosition() will be fine for point1. what about point2.

Comment: Rather than adding polygons every second you would store the last location (initially null) and compare it to the current location, which you periodically collect. If the last location is null you set it to the current location. Otherwise if the distance between last and current location exceeds a threshold you would add a new polygon from the last to the current location and update the last location to the current. The lower the threshold the more detail you see but the more polygons will be added to the map. So depending on how long this goes on for you may want a higher or lower threshold.

Comment: If you want to further optimize this you could apply a track reduction algorithm, i.e. if the movement is straight or rather "relatively" straight, so that points A, B, C and D are on a line you could remove the inner points B and C. Again, a threshold can be used to determine the level of straightness resulting in either more detail or more points. If you are interested in this let me know.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty with the polygons. They appear but not always perpendicular to the bearing or heading. If you could look at my other post I would appreciate it. Thanks. Also if I use the computeHeading or getBearing I have the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585189/make-polygons-perpendicular-to-bearing-in-google-maps-android